# how to get user's position in Google maps API?

Tags: google-maps

I noticed that the google maps api has a option "sensor".

Comment: Please confirm whether you are trying to implement this using HTML5?

Comment: i want get this by using javascript.

Comment: Please see the link in my answer, it uses HTML5 and Javascript. Which OS are you targeting Android, iPhone or are you using Qt?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"sensor" in GMaps API is not an option, it is an information parameter. Here is what [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/guide.html#Sensor) say:

> Use of the Google Maps API(s) requires
>   that you indicate whether your
>   application is using a sensor (such as
>   a GPS locator) to determine the user's
>   location in any Maps API library or
>   service requests.

Google Maps doesn't know anything of your users, so it cannot provide their location. It is the other way around: you can determine user's location and give it to Google Maps to place a location pointer and so on.

You have several options to get user's location in JS:

- W3C (HTML 5) [Geolocation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/) (needs browser support);
- [Google Gears API](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html) (needs Google Gears installed);
- gelocation by IP, for instance, [MaxMind](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/maxmind-geoip) and [HostIP](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/hostip.info) (the least accurate, but works most of the time).

If you're developing for a sensor-equipped device (like a mobile phone with GPS reciever) there should be some vendor-specific ways to get the location directly from the device.

Answer (score 3):

The approach to "get user's position in Google maps" is dependent on which devices you are targeting.

The [HTML 5 Approach](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Mobile) is meant for Androids, iPhones and other mobile platforms that have support for HTML5. In this case the browser is able to obtain the co-ordinates directly from the GPS without you having to write the code in the native language.

However if you are developing on say QT to target Symbians and the like, you'll need to write the code in the native language (C++ in my case) to acquire  the co-ordinates from your GPS and post it to the [server](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html) to update the user's current location. You'll find details about retrieving co-ordinates using Qt Mobility API [here](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Get_continuous_location_updates_using_Qt_Mobility_API).

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get the user's position is to include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

in your page.

This creates a javascript object "google.loader.ClientLocation" which contains the user's latitude, longitude and address.

Example:

```
google.loader.ClientLocation = {
    "latitude": 51.817,
    "longitude": 19.3,
    "address": {
        "city": "Aleksandrow Lodzki",
        "region": "Lodz",
        "country": "Poland",
        "country_code": "PL"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For google maps API v3 it is described here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics

Answer (score 0):

The sensor parameter is no longer required. from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation#SpecifyingSensor):

> The Google Maps API previously required that you include the sensor parameter to indicate whether your application used a sensor to determine the user's location. This parameter is no longer required.